# Select, выводящий данные в одну строку в несколько столбцов

Tags: sql

В БД ORACLE есть таблица, хранящая номера телефонов.
Например у этого id_owner имеется 4 номера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо сделать такой select, чтобы данные группировались по ID_OWNER, вывелись в одну строку и каждый номер вывелся в отдельный столбец, т.е типа:
id_owner | comm | comm | comm | comm |

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сформировать такую выборку.

Comment: Это называется PIVOT. Не каждая СУБД это поддерживает, ибо нереляционно. А кто поддерживает - всяк делает по своему. Указывайте точно СУБД, включая точную версию. Но ещё лучше - делайте это на клиенте его средствами.

Comment: Скажите, а зачем вам так надо сделать? А если comm будет, к примеру, 500 штук?

Comment: СУБД ORACLE 11 

Там не более 4 таких comm.
Просят выполнить выгрузку из БД в таком формате, вот хотел узнать, можно ли такую сформировать

Comment: Спросите их - зачем им такой формат? Вообще, бывает в задачу разработчика входит умение убедить заказчика не делать так, а сделать по-другому, потому что это более рационально на основе каких-либо доводов. В общем, убедить того в том, что он предлагает - ересь.... даже если оно толковое, но не хочется делать :D

Comment: Выгрузите в одно поле, через запятую, или другой разделитель например с помощью функции listagg. А дальше на клиенте преобразуйте в тот вид, который от вас ожидают

Comment: А если все таки именно колонки, то есть pivot https://www.fors.ru/upload/magazine/02/html_texts/w_dev_ora11g_pivot.html предварительно телефоны в пределах id_owner надо будет пронумеровать (row_number() over(partition by id_owner)), что бы за эти номера зацепиться в pivot'е.

Comment: думаю через listagg будет достаточно, спасибо!

Comment: [offtop]Красиво смотрится... тёзки - как будто автор сам с собой поговорил :-)[/offtop]